# Storing data by 'week' in Firebase / Firestore

Tags: firebase, database-design, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I'm trying to design my store data structure to store Shopping Lists which we are set to specific weeks.

Here is my initial approach:

```
// api/users

{
    user: 'Karl Taylor',
    userId: 43
    shoppingListId: 1
}
```

Then I would query `api/shopping_lists/1`

I was going to set the week entry to be the first day of the week. e.g Monday 19th March 2018 which would include everything from Monday the 19th to Sunday the 25th.

```
// api/shopping_lists/1

{
    userId: 43
    weeks: {
        19-03-2018: ['Eggs', 'Milk'] // week 1
        26-03-2018: ['Pasta', 'Cheese'] // week 2
    }
}
```

Any good resources on this kind of data structuring would be great.

Comment: As I commented on Peter's answer, I'd recommend using an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. For example: `YYYY-Www`, e.g. `2018-W1`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for this advice Frank, I'll integrate this into this new flow.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
Users
  useruid
    name:userx
    email:userx@gmail.com
  useruid
    name:usery
    email:usery@gmail.com

Daysoftheweek
     randomid
        date: 2018-03-19
        item1:eggs
        item2:popcorn
        username: userx
      randomid
         date:2018-03-26
         item1:pizza
         item2: pepsi
         username:userx
```

Then you can query `orderByChild("date").equalTo(2018-03-19)` and you will get the list of items for that week

Comment: Won't this query get all shopping-lists for all users for a specific date? Where as I would just want to get a specific shopping-list for 1 user for a specific week

Comment: yes this query is just an example `orderByChild("date").equalTo(19-03-2018)` it will give you what you said in the above comment. But to get of a specific user, you can just get the current user and query on that also

Comment: Please never store dates in this format `26-03-2018`. While it reads natural to users, it's a format that's wrought with problems for sorting and filtering. Instead either store them as a timestamp, or in an ISO 8601 format such as `2018-03-26`. Those formats both allow sorting and filtering dates.

Comment: @PeterHaddad I am aiming to show a list of items for a whole week rather than a specific day.

Comment: yes item1 and item2 are items for the week that starts with `2018-03-19`

Answer (score 2):

A natural way of structuring this is to have a lists sub-collection under the user.

So an example would be:

```
Collection: /users
  -> Document: <auto id> (acts as user ID)
     {
       user: 'Karl Taylor'
     }
     Collection /lists
     -> Document: "2018-03-19"
        {
          items: ['milk', 'eggs']
        }
     -> Document: "2018-03-26"
        {
          items: ['pasta', 'cheese']
        }
```

In the console, the `users` collection would look like this:
[image: View of the users collection in the Firebase Console]

The `lists` collection would look like this:
[image: View of the lists collection in the Firebase Console]

This allows you get all week lists for a user with:

```
db.collection("users").doc(userid).collection("lists")
  .get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });
```

Or just a specific list with a lookup:

```
db.collection("users").doc(userid).collection("lists").doc("2018-03-19")
  .get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
      // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  });
```